# Want to show a view on clicking at the location of image

Tags: android, canvas, android-custom-view, android-photoview

I want to show a view on canvas of the image. This view will typically allow the user to add the information of the clicked position. Now I am using [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView). On tap of image, I get the location and made the canvas out of it. How can I show the view on canvas when the user taps the image? Any help will be highly appreciated. I have attached the image for reference.[image]

Comment: you should not show view on canvas. You can add a view to the container on specified coordinates.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Agreed. But my requirement is a little different. I should be able to zoom to the image and add the view. If I add the view on container, the zoom functionality will go away i.e. on the fixed container only, I would be able to add views but this is not the desired output. Plz let me know for any other thoughts